# User Defined issues Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm a new Mac Os user, before I worked on windows.
I'm trying to write programs on pawn, but on mac there is not "real" version on it. 
I found on official website that you can you can run the program PAWNO threw Xcode, but I can't  do it properly.

I got a error - User Defined Issues, what does it mean and how to fix it?

Thanks.

And link where I found it.
http://www.compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm

Comment: I don't know anything about pawn but if you show the actual error and where it appears, it would be easier to make suggestions.

Comment: Soo.. http://i.imgur.com/CrIsT5w.png this is a screenshot what I'm getting when i try to build it.

Answer (score 0):

You are building for a 64-bit Intel architecture but the header file you're using doesn't support that (**i386**).  Try setting your project/target settings for building as a 32-bit application.

Comment: can you help me how to do that? I tried to change it to 32 bit, but nothing happened, maybe i did something wrong

Comment: Choose your target and the build settings page.  Make sure i386 is listed in Valid Architectures.  Choose 32-bit Intel from the architectures list.  If that doesn't work, maybe the people who supplied the code have an answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but nothing really helped, i'll try to contact them. I think it's just because of the new version of the Xcode